# Angular 2 interaction between dynamically created components

Tags: angular

I'm trying to set up interaction between parent-child component, the issue is that the child component is dynamically created using `ComponentResolver`.

I have a parent which creates its child like this:

```
this._componentResolver.resolveComponent(this.component).then((factory) => {
  this.componentRef = this.include.createComponent(factory);
});
```

I can call functions on the created child using `this.componentRef.instance.childListen();`

But I'd like to call a function on my parent, from my child. I tried using an eventEmitter:

`@Output() parentBuyToy = new EventEmitter<boolean>();`

```
childDo() {
    this.parentBuyToy.emit(true);
}
```

But the HTML looks fishy, I don't think this can work:

```
<div #include (buyThis)="parentBuyToy($event)"></div>
```

I think I should be using the instance to achieve child to parent communication, is this right?

Comment: I would just use a service.